# protocol upon addition, asking again and again, cleared derived data folder also

Tags: xcode, protocols

I am integrating autocomplete from heremap, `NMAResultListener`.
Upon adding protocol stubs, it's asking the same again and again

I cleared derived data folder also. Still no help

```
class AddWorkVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NMAResultListener {
    func request(_ request: NMARequest, didCompleteWithData data: Any?, error: Error?) {
    }
    var  mainWorkTextField : SearchTextField! = nil

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

It should not ask for "add protocol stubs" again and again

Comment: It looks to me like you are implementing the objective-c version, try `func requestDidComplete(_ request: NMARequest, data: Any?, error: Error?)`

Answer (score 0):

The protocol method is defined differently for objective-c and swift. It's possible that something is annotated wrongly, or that the protocol stubs are being added wrongly.

According to the [documentation](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/api_reference_jazzy/Protocols/NMAResultListener.html#%2Fc:objc(pl)NMAResultListener(im)request:didCompleteWithData:error:), the Swift method signature is

```swift
func requestDidComplete(_ request: NMARequest, data: Any?, error: Error?)
```

Comment: class AddWorkVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate , NMAResultListener {
    
   func requestDidComplete(_ request: NMARequest, data: Any?, error: Error?)
   {
    
    }

Comment: Command-click on `NMAResultListener` and it will show you the interface for the protocol. Perhaps that's different again?

Comment: Thanks for help. It didnt work. I am using NMARequestCompletionBlock. Its working fine.